# Lipschitzness of product map on $L^2 \times L^2$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroups

Is the map $(u,v) \rightarrow uv$ a Lipschitz map from $L^2(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

I am particularly interested in existence of local solutions of PDEs of the form by arguing that the nonlinearity in the following PDE is locally Lipschitz.

$u_t =  \Delta u -a uv  $

$v_t =  \Delta v  +a uv $

Comment: Wouldn't that map arrive in $L^1$ instead of $L^2$?

Comment: Non-trivial bilinear continuous maps are locally Lipschitz, but not globally (think of the simple multiplication of real numbers, $(x, y) \mapsto xy$)